# Unable to logout from facebook in react-native

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

- In my react-native app, I am unable to **logout** from `Facebook`(Chrome Custom Tab) on the press of a  custom button.
- When I click to login it shows the continue button with previously account logged in. This screen shows up every time when a user has previously logged in and what if a new user has to login.
- Also app setup with facebook developer account is completed.
- I am using [fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)

What I have tried to `logout`:

**First method:**

```
LoginManager.logOut();
```

**Second Method:** (Getting null accessToken)

```
FBLogout = (accessToken) => {
            let logout =
                new GraphRequest(
                    "me/permissions/",
                    {
                        accessToken: accessToken,
                        httpMethod: 'DELETE'
                    },
                    (error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                        } else {
                            LoginManager.logOut();
                        }
                    });
            new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(logout).start();
        };
```

What I see:
[image]

Comment: This is the permission screen that allows the user to give permission like email, phone etc.

Comment: But every time, I want to show the login screen. This screen shows up every time when a user has previously logged in.

Comment: This is the screenshot of Chrome Custom Tab of Facebook SDK. Open the Google Chrome app and logout from Facebook and try again.

Comment: Can we do it with code and without manually going into Chrome tabs ? Opening chrome tab and logging out works but with code it doesn't.

Comment: There may be a way but I don't know about it. Thanks